# AngularJS authentication happens only on multiple fast clicks

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication

I have an angular app based on the angularjs/php authentication sample. Due to some reason, login only occurs if I click the login button in rapid succession for about four times. But if we use the developer tool, we can see that in the back end the authentication is successful in the first click itself, but the view doesn't update.

Anybody have faced such an issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: It looks like if i change the setTimeout value to 2000 it logs in, in just 1 click. If the value is reduced, it takes a lot of fast clicks.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    principal.authenticate($scope.details); 
    if ($scope.returnToState) 
        $state.go($scope.returnToState.name, $scope.returnToStateParams);
    else $state.go('home');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: That sounds like your auth is running asynchronously, however, without a more complete code view. We cannot tell. Furthermore, there are many auth examples so you should post which one you are referring to.

Comment: Basically it is working now, with just one click when i made the value 2000. Earlier it was 600. I believe i used a modified version of this sample http://angularcode.com/user-authentication-using-angularjs-php-mysql/